# 90s Children’s show with aliens (possibly BBC)

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

So this has been bugging me for years - but I remember a show that aired in the UK in the 90s (it could be British, maybe BBC - it also may not be) about aliens trying to track down humans (who may also have been aliens taking refuge on earth).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this a live-action or animated show?  What did the aliens look like?  How did you (the audience) know they were aliens?  How were they tracking people, detective-type methods or secret technology?

Comment: Was it new in the 90s? Do you remember anything about main characters? Was it children or a show about adults aimed at children?

Comment: There's not a lot to go on here; perhaps you could have a look at the tips in [this FAQ](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-di-container) and [edit] in some more details that might help narrow it down.

Answer (score 5):

If it is BBC and mid 1990's it is almost certainly Aliens In the Family. Which makes this question a duplicate as I have previously answered a question IDing this very show,

The story elements you describe are a very strong match for this show. Aliens in the Family is spot on for the timescale, matches being made/shown on bbc in the Uk and does heavily feature aliens disguised as humans taking refuge on earth, being hunted by other aliens.

Here is a link to an episode on Youtube

Comment: The answer should stand on its own. How does it match?

Comment: @fuzzyboots. Aliens in the Family is spot on for the timescale, matches being made/shown on bbl in the Uk and does heavily feature aliens disguised as humans taking refuge on earth, being hunted by other aliens.

Comment: :-D Part of the problem is that none of this is in the answer.

Comment: Just tagging https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205124/80-90s-uk-childrens-drama-series-about-an-alien-boy-with-radio-weapon/205147#205147 as the accepted answer that would be the duplicate if this one were accepted.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots fair point, I've added them in...

Answer (score 3):

Possibly "[Halfway Across the Galaxy and Turn Left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfway_Across_the_Galaxy_and_Turn_Left)", which aired on CITV in 1994 and 1996. It's an Australian show, and features a family of aliens who had to flee the authorities on planet Zyrgon and attempt to hide on earth, pretending to be humans.